# Does ピッとGo mean anything?

Tags: culture

Probably it is more cultural question than the language one, but I can't figure out if ピッとGo is just a name for the Times Car point program and does not mean anything or is a some kind of play of words.

Comment: I'd assume it's onomatopoetic - as "グッと" and "パッと" in essence are "with a *gu*" and "with a *pa*" (as I've understood it), this should be "with a *pi*". That'd make this "go with a *pi*" or "go in a *pi*", which I suppose sounds "fast".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ピッ is a common onomatopoeia that describes a short beep sound. "ピッとGo" just means something like "Beep-and-go". I don't think it's a pun for something. Particularly, I don't think it's related to *pit* as in *pit stop*.

Comment: It's definititely not related to "pit" - if so, it'd be spelled "ピット". "と" is the particle, in this case.